# How do I bind MVC POST names/values to controller ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm trying to POST a HTML form to my `PersonController.AppSave()` but I think there is a problem with the mapping/binding.

I am sending two values via POST `{ Person.id: '12345, XApplication.dateOfApplication: '01/01/2014'}`, however my controller doesn't seem to directly recognise these values, as it is expecting `XApplication` (with good reason).

How do I bind these values? for example I want to bind `Person.id` to `XApplication.personId`.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Thanks for your help

```
@model MyNameSpace.ViewModels.StudentViewModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Person.id, "default")
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dateOfApplication" class="col-md-3 control-label">Date of Application</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.XApplication.dateOfApplication, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                </div>
            </div><!-- form-group -->
        </div><!-- .12 -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
    }


namespace MyNameSpace.ViewModels
{
      public class PersonViewModel
      {
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public XApplication XApplications { get; set; }
      }
  }

namespace MyNameSpace.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
      [HttpPost]
      [Route("person/appSave")]
      public ActionResult AppSave(XApplication application)
      {
        return Redirect("/person/app/" + application.personId);
      }
    }
}

namespace MyNameSpace.Models
{
    public partial class XApplication
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int personId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime dateOfApplication { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your controller action to accept your `StudentViewModel` as it's parameter.

Comment: Giving that a go now! Sorry I edited to PersonViewModel.

Comment: That worked thanks! I noticed it isn't respecting my [Required] attribute when I submit the form with a blank dateOfApplication?

Comment: [Required] on non nullable types is a bit useless because if you don't set a value you get the default value for the type (DateTime.MinValue in this case). Try changing the property to a `DateTime?`